# Style doesn't apply to HTML5 custom element

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

Ok, this is a really strange case, I've got a page where I'm styling a "custom" tag.

```
<comment>This is a comment</comment>
```

In production, I output a simple style in the html template so it doesn't show up:

```
<style type="text/css">
    comment {display:none;}
</style>
```

The strange thing is that if I edit the `<style>` node in Chrome's dev tools and add something insignificant, like one space ... it works all of a sudden. Here's a picture of the `comment` node's style when the page first loads:

[image: on first page load]

And then this is after I add one space to the `style` element

[image]

Any thoughts on what might be going on?

Comment: Have your registered your custom element? `document.registerElement('comment');`

Comment: Can't really seem to reproduce this. I'd go with @enyce12 though, it sounds like Chrome skips it at first because it isn't sure what to make of it and only later learns about the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to register your custom element and separate it with a dash (`-`):

```
document.registerElement('x-comment');
```

Your element must contain a dash, otherwise the browser won't be able to recognize it as a custom element.

From the [specs](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#dfn-custom-element-type):

> The custom element type identifies a custom element interface and is a
>   sequence of characters that must match the NCName production, must
>   contain a U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS character, and must not contain any
>   uppercase ASCII letters. [...]

Comment: Whoa ... T.I.L.! that seems to have worked @enyce12 :D

Comment: wait ... although, I didn't use the `x-`. Is there documentation that points to this being a requirement?